# Highcharts, zoom in bottom navigation bar

Tags: charts, highcharts

Call function `drawTable` when I zoom on main chart, but don't call when I zoom on bottom navigation bar.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.6/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/chart/events-selection/

```
 window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                chart : {
                    renderTo : 'container',
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    events: {
                      selection: function(event) {
                            if (event.xAxis) {
                                drawTable(event.xAxis[0].min, event.xAxis[0].max);
                            } else {
                                $('#table').html('Selection reset');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'Total Traf'
                },


                xAxis : {
                    maxZoom : 14 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
                },

                series : [{
                        name : 'TT',
                        data : data,
                        tooltip: {
                            yDecimals: 2
                        }
                    }]
            });
        });
```

Comment: I would love to help but I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is some what in the direction of what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/7VgJM/3/

I was not quite sure what you were asking, but made an educated guess.